# How to use ionic 2 UI in telerik appbuilder

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, telerik, ionic2, telerik-appbuilder

I did a hybrid application in ionic 2. Now I preferred to create this project into telerik appbuilder. So I tried to use ionic 2 UI in to telerik appbuilder through bower_components. Using bower I added ionic library to telerik appbuilder project. But Ionic UI is not working in this project.

ionic library link is https://github.com/driftyco/ionic

How can I call bower ionic component into my index.html page.

My code is

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/ionic/src/themes/util.scss" /> -->
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/ionic/src/themes/ionic.theme.default.scss" />
 <script src="bower_components/ionic/src/index.js"></script> 
 <ion-content class="login-content" padding> 
 <ion-col class="signup-col">
  <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid">Login</button>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-item>
   <ion-label color="navy" floating>Schedule Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" color="navy" name="sname" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: pretty sure you are going to have a really hard time trying to implement 2 different frameworks together, that both essentially do the same thing + the amount of code rot you are going to have will be so much.

Comment: You don't have to use bower to load Ionic. You can just reference the JS/CSS like you would with any other app. Telerik AppBuilder lets you develop/build/test in the cloud, it's not a JS framework.